# OR operator if ( ) to look for decimal point string javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

anybody know why this doesn’t work i am trying to pass a number or a “.” point in the if function. it's part of a calculator object that sends a decimal point on click jquery event. for some reason console log shows the number works but decimal point doesn't. http://codepen.io/rush86999/pen/QyJMPo?editors=0010
`else if (!(isNaN(this.pressed) || (this.pressed == ".")` 
decimal point

Comment: the argument gets passed but i've checked "." doesn't pass through using console.log

Answer (score 0):

You were checking that (.) is a number.

> !(isNaN(this.pressed) : this means you are checking for (.) as a number but actually it is not. Remove this from your code this will start working. Or
>   Make it if ((!isNaN(this.pressed) || (this.pressed == ".")

```
var Calculator = {

  numberOrDecimalPoint: "",
  operation: "",
  pressed: "",

  //helper object to translate value to id without "#" needed for internal model
  valueToId: {
    "+": "add",
    "-": "subtract",
    "*": "multiply",
    "/": "divide",
    "=": "equals",
    "1": "one",
    "2": "two",
    "3": "three",
    "4": "four",
    "5": "five",
    "6": "six",
    "7": "seven",
    "8": "eight",
    "9": "nine",
    "0": "zero",
    ".": "point"
  },

  //display function object to display stuff
  display(value) {
    //reset display marker to reset the display
    var resetDisplay = false;

    //check the arugments if number set it to display or if an operation highlight the function 
    if (isNaN(value[0]) && value[0] != ".") {
      //highlight selected operation
      $(id[value]).css("padding", "5px");
      //if clear pressed set display to zero
      if (value == "clear") {
        $("#display").text("0");
      }

      //set reset display to true
      resetDisplay = true;

    } else {
      //display the value by concatenating it unless reset display is set to true after operation pressed
      if (resetDisplay = true) {
        $("#display").text(value);
        //reset the display to not true to continue to concatenate
        resetDisplay = false;
      } else {
        //continue to concatenate display
        $("display").text($("#display").text().concat(value));
        console.log($("#display").text().concat(value));
      }
    }

    //helper object that correlates with #id for each button
    var id = {
      "+": "#add",
      "-": "#subtract",
      "*": "#multiply",
      "/": "#divide",
      "=": "#equals",
      "1": "#one",
      "2": "#two",
      "3": "#three",
      "4": "#four",
      "5": "#five",
      "6": "#six",
      "7": "#seven",
      "8": "#eight",
      "9": "#nine",
      "0": "#zero",
      ".": "#point"
    }

  },

  //lets make the store an object
  /** store will store number in an array for tens and hundredths etc while a second number  in another array, it also has an array for operations **/
  store: {
    //array of first number
    firstNumber: [],
    //array of stored operations
    storedOperation: [],
    //array of second number
    secondNumber: [],

    //helper function to check if values stored 
    notEmpty() {

      return (firstNumber[0] != null && secondNumber[0] != null);
    },
    //first Number not empty
    firstNumberNotEmpty() {

      return (firstNumber[0] != null);
    },
    //storedOperation not empty
    storedOperationNotEmpty() {

      return (storedOperation[0] != null);
    },

    //helper function to check and see if a decimal point is already present
    decimalPointPresent(array) {
      return array.indexOf(".");
    },

  },

  //operator function as an object
  operator: {
    "-": function(x, y) {
      return x - y;
    },
    "+": function(x, y) {
      return x + y;
    },
    "*": function(x, y) {
      return x * y;
    },
    "/": function(x, y) {
      return x / y;
    }
  },

  clear() {
    //empty everything in the store
    this.store.firstNumber = [];
    this.store.storedOperation = [];
    this.store.secondNumber = [];

  },

  equals() {

    //equals similar to second operation take the first operate on the second number and store it in the first but do not empty the storedOperation

    //pop the secondNumber array and concatenate it into a whole number
    var stringSecondNumber = this.store.secondNumber.join();
    //empty the array secondNumber
    this.store.secondNumber = [];

    //convert the string to float
    secondNumber = parsefloat(stringSecondNumber);

    //pop the firstNumber array and concatenate it into a float
    var stringfirstNumber = this.store.secondNumber.join();
    secondNumber = parsefloat(stringSecondNumber);
    this.store.firstNumber = [];

    //pop the operation previously pressed in the store, perform the operation and push the new operation and push the new value into firstNumber 
    var oldOperation = this.store.storedOperation.pop();
    var result = this.operator[oldOperation](firstNumber, secondNumber);
    this.store.firstNumber.push(result);
    this.store.storedOperation.push(oldOperation);
    //check for null
    if (oldOperation != null) {
      //call display
      this.display(oldOperation);
    }
  },

  press() {
    this.pressed = arguments[0];
console.log(arguments[0]);
    if (this.pressed.length === 1) {
      //it is not a number and it is not a deceimal point and not empty
      if (isNaN(this.pressed) && this.pressed != "." && this.pressed != null) {

        //it's a string operation
        this.operation = this.pressed[0];

        //operation is clear send it to clear function
        if (this.operation == "clear") {
          this.clear();
          //call display
          this.display(this.operation);
        }
        //operation is equals call it here
        if (this.operation == "equals") {
          this.equals();
          this.display(this.operation)
        }

        //if operation is pressed second time ie already storedOperation but store numbers are empty so empty the first operation and put the new one in
        if (this.store.storedOperationNotEmptry() && this.store.notEmpty() != true) {

          //empty the stored operation
          this.store.storedOperation = [];

          //just store the new operation
          this.store.storedOperation.push(this.operation);

          //call display
          this.display(this.operation);
        }

        //if operation is pressed second time ie storedOperation is not empty && store is not empty
        if (this.store.storedOperationNotEmpty() && this.store.notEmpty()) {
          //pop the secondNumber array and concatenate it into a whole number
          var stringSecondNumber = this.store.secondNumber.join();

          //empty the array secondNumber
          this.store.secondNumber = [];

          //convert the string to float
          secondNumber = parsefloat(stringSecondNumber);

          //pop the firstNumber array and concatenate it into a float
          var stringfirstNumber = this.store.secondNumber.join();
          secondNumber = parsefloat(stringSecondNumber);
          this.store.firstNumber = [];

          //pop the operation previously pressed in the store, perform the operation and push the new operation and push the new value into firstNumber 
          var oldOperation = this.store.storedOperation.pop();
          //empty operation
          this.store.storedOperation = [];
          var result = this.operator[oldOperation](firstNumber, secondNumber);
          this.store.firstNumber.push(result);
          this.store.storedOperation.push(this.operation); //call the display results and show the results
          this.display(result);
        }
        //if the operation is pressed for the first time after being cleared or pressing the equals button 

        //check to see if first number is stored and first time pressed operation
        if (this.store.storedOperationNotEmpty() != true && this.store.firstNumberNotEmpty()) {
          this.store.storedOperation.push(this.operation);

          //call display here
          this.display(this.operation);

        }
        //always check the argument is not null and is a number
      } else if  (!(isNaN(this.pressed)) || this.pressed == ".") {
        // can be number or decimal point
        this.numberOrDecimalPoint = this.pressed[0];

        console.log(this.pressed+"YEYEE");

        //if this is not a chain of operations ie there is only one storedOperation and first number was stored already
        if (this.store.storedOperation.length === 1 && this.store.firstNumberNotEmpty() && this.store.storedOperationNotEmpty()) {

          //push the second number as long 
          if (this.numberOrDecimalPoint == "." && this.store.decimalPointPresent(this.store.secondNumer) != true) {
            this.store.secondNumber.push(this.numberOrDecimalPoint);
          } else if (this.numberOrDecimalPoint != ".") {
            //store the second number
            this.store.secondNumber.push(this.numberOrDecimalPoint);
          }

        }
        //still on the first number so keep storing it until operation is pressed ie operation is stored in the store
        if (this.numberOrDecimalPoint == ".") {
          console.log(this.numberOrDecimalPoint);
          if (this.store.decimalPointPresent(this.store.firstNumber) != true) {
            this.store.firstNumber.push(this.numberOrDecimalPoint);
          }
        } else if (this.numberOrDecimalPoint != ".") {
          this.store.firstNumber.push(this.numberOrDecimalPoint);

          //store it in numberorDecimal for display
          this.numberOrDecimalPoint = this.store.firstNumber.join("");
          console.log(this.store.firstNumber);
        }

        //call display here at the end
        this.display(this.numberOrDecimalPoint);
      }

    }

  }

};

var calculator1 = Object.create(Calculator);
//jquery for click event to call calculator
$("#clear").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("clear");
});
$("#add").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("add");
});
$("#subtract").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("subtract");
});
$("#multiply").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("multiply");
});
$("#divide").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("divide");
});
$("#equals").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("equals");
});
$("#one").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("1");
});
$("#two").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("2");
});
$("#three").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("3");
});
$("#four").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("4");
});
$("#five").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("5");
});
$("#six").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("6");
});
$("#seven").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("7");
});
$("#eight").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("8");
});
$("#nine").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("9");
});
$("#zero").click(function() {
  calculator1.press("0");
});
$("#point").click(function() {
  calculator1.press(".");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your parenthesis are in the wrong spaces. Your codepen has:

```
} else if (!(isNaN(this.pressed) || (this.pressed == "."))) {
```

Which, evaluates whether `this.pressed` is not a number or equal to a period, then inverts it using the logical not.

I think you really want:

```
} else if (!isNaN(this.pressed) || this.pressed == ".") {
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your logic, all of them at this block

```
// Index of returns -1 if the value is not found into the array
if (this.store.decimalPointPresent(this.store.firstNumber) === -1) {
  this.store.firstNumber.push(this.numberOrDecimalPoint);

  // This adjust the display to show the "." and the numbers
  this.numberOrDecimalPoint = this.store.firstNumber.join("");
}
else {
    // This prevent an event if a dot is already pressed once
    return false;
}
```

I also changed some CSS properties to adjust the display of the calc, I added a position relative in your calculator div, to take it as a reference to the display, and after I changed the top, left, bottom and right properties at the display

```
#calculator {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #cc9900;
  padding: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

#display {
  background-color: #ff9999;
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: inherit;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

You can see the example running here http://codepen.io/guilhermelucio/pen/VeRegL?editors=0100